# Different number session during authentication with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, session

I reading this article [on Medium](https://medium.com/@evangow/server-authentication-basics-express-sessions-passport-and-curl-359b7456003d)
I came to place where it write number of the sessions [link on Pastbin](https://pastebin.com/pxAv4ifr)

In this article written that after many times invocation of this command "client $ curl -X GET http://localhost:3000 -b cookie-file.txt"
i must have got one and the same result. But in the output i have

```
Inside the session middleware
de5b7edc-09e7-47dc-b9f8-8ac0179ec1ea
Inside the homepage callback function
f559ee33-2928-41a0-94aa-39025578cbc6
Inside the session middleware
de5b7edc-09e7-47dc-b9f8-8ac0179ec1ea
Inside the homepage callback function
fcc48f22-2000-44f5-8f19-13adb1bf8191
Inside the session middleware
de5b7edc-09e7-47dc-b9f8-8ac0179ec1ea
Inside the homepage callback function
dc696106-10ea-413a-b60e-b1e725820311
```

I don't understand why i getting distinct  number session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {    
        req.session.init = "initProgram";  //this is very important for sessions, we need to initialize it for authentication.
        next();
    });
```

Everytime you call the route, you are creating a new session.
When you call http://localhost:3000, initialize the session, then use the cookie on subsequent calls to only use that session.

Comment: Omg, im so embarrassed, perhapse i use curl in wrong way. Now i start command "curl -X GET localhost:3000 -c cookie-file.txt " with a flag " -c" and after that same command with the flag " -b". Just now after many repetition  this command "curl -X GET localhost:3000 -b cookie-file.txt" i've got one and the same a number of session. 
Probable i need rewrite the file cookie-file.txt because life-span  of  the session  is expired.